# React useSpeechRecognition is in diffrent languages

Tags: reactjs

I am using the hook of react useSpeechRecognition
but the voice-to-speech is in the device's language.

How can I set it to be always in English?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/JamesBrill/react-speech-recognition/blob/master/docs/API.md) you can set language to English like this;

```
SpeechRecognition.startListening({ language: 'en-US' })
```